# Animating bar chart using d3 and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have the following bar chart code in react and d3 (following the declarative way). I would like to animate the bars and axes when they are first rendered, and after that whenever the data change, like using d3 api using the imperative way (with React I would like to keep things the declarative way). So far I managed to animate the bars using `react-spring` when they are first rendered, and when I delete a bar by clicking on it, the width of the bars is adjusted. However, I am not sure how to animate the axes when the data is updated. I am also not sure how to animate the position of the bars after one of them is deleted. I am thinking I may need an array of `useRef` for the x position, height and axes's ticks, but not sure how to go about it.

To summarize my questions:

1. How can animate the x position and height of the bars when the data is updated?
2. How can I animate the axes's ticks and labels when the data is updated?

data.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "country": "China",
    "population": 1400000000
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "India",
    "population": 1200000000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "USA",
    "population": 450000000
  }
]
```

App.js

```
import BarChart from './components/BarChart';

function App() {
  return <BarChart />;
}

export default App;
```

BarChart.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { scaleBand, scaleLinear, max, format } from 'd3';
import initialData from '../data/data.json';
import { AxisBottom, AxisLeft } from './Axes';
import AnimatedMarks from './AnimatedMarks';
import Marks from './Marks';
import { useState } from 'react';

const svgDimensions = {
  width: 600,
  height: 600,
};

const margins = {
  left: 100,
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 100,
};

const gDimensions = {
  width: svgDimensions.width - margins.left - margins.right,
  height: svgDimensions.height - margins.top - margins.bottom,
};

const xValue = (d) => d.country;
const yValue = (d) => d.population;

const BarChart = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max(data, yValue)])
    .range([gDimensions.height, 0]);

  const xScale = scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(xValue))
    .range([0, gDimensions.width])
    .paddingInner(0.1)
    .paddingOuter(0.1);

  const prevBandwidth = useRef(xScale.bandwidth());
  

  useEffect(() => {
    prevBandwidth.current = xScale.bandwidth();
  }, [data]);

  c

  const deleteMarkOnClick = (i) => {
    setData(data.filter((d) => d.id !== i));
  };

  return (
    <svg width={svgDimensions.width} height={svgDimensions.height}>
      <g
        width={gDimensions.width}
        height={gDimensions.height}
        transform={`translate(${margins.left},${margins.top})`}
      >
        <AxisLeft
          yScale={yScale}
          tickFormat={(n) => format('.2s')(n).replace('G', 'B')}
        />

        <AxisBottom xScale={xScale} gDimensions={gDimensions} />

        <text
          className='xAxis-label'
          x={gDimensions.width / 2}
          y={gDimensions.height + 50}
        >
          COUNTRY
        </text>

        {data.map((d) => (
          <AnimatedMarks
            prevBandwidth={prevBandwidth}
            deleteMarkOnClick={deleteMarkOnClick}
            d={d}
            xScale={xScale}
            yScale={yScale}
            gDimensions={gDimensions}
            xValue={xValue}
            yValue={yValue}
          />
        ))}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

AnimatedMarks.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';
const AnimatedMarks = ({
  d,
  xScale,
  yScale,
  gDimensions,
  xValue,
  yValue,
  deleteMarkOnClick,
  prevBandwidth,
}) => {
  const style = useSpring({
    config: {
      duration: 1000,
    },
    from: {
      width: prevBandwidth.current,
      y: gDimensions.height,
      height: 0,
      opacity: 0,
    },
    to: {
      width: xScale.bandwidth(),
      y: yScale(yValue(d)),
      height: gDimensions.height - yScale(yValue(d)),
      opacity: 1,
    },
  });

  return (
    <animated.rect
      onClick={() => deleteMarkOnClick(d.id)}
      className='mark'
      key={d.id}
      x={xScale(xValue(d))}
      // y={yScale(yValue(d))}
      // width={xScale.bandwidth()}
      {...style}
      // height={gDimensions.height - yScale(yValue(d))}
    />
  );
};

export default AnimatedMarks;
```

Axes.js

```
export const AxisBottom = ({ xScale, gDimensions }) =>
  xScale.domain().map((xTickValue) => (
    <g
      className='tick'
      key={xTickValue}
      transform={`translate(${xScale(xTickValue) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2},${
        gDimensions.height + 20
      })`}
    >
      <line y1='-15' y2='-20' />
      <text>{xTickValue}</text>
    </g>
  ));

export const AxisLeft = ({ yScale, tickFormat }) =>
  yScale.ticks().map((yTickValue) => (
    <g
      className='tick'
      key={yTickValue}
      transform={`translate(0,${yScale(yTickValue)})`}
    >
      <line x1='5' x2='15' stroke='black' />
      <text dy='0.32em' style={{ textAnchor: 'end' }}>
        {tickFormat(yTickValue)}
      </text>
    </g>
  ));
```

EDIT: This is the code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nice-tereshkova-7mpom?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Can you prepare a working sandbox and post a link to it?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I added the code into codesandbox, and included the link in my question.

Comment: Just checked your sandbox. You need to recreate `xScale` and `yScale` each time you change the data in your `BarChart` component: `xScale = useMemo(..., [data])`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky This happens automatically when I update the data though, because data is a state variable. The xScale and yScale are updated correctly, and the axes ticks and labels change correctly. My question is how to animate the change in axes ticks and labels. In d3 api we use `.transition().duration()`, but in React when we use the declarative way, how to implement this transition? I implemented the transition for the bandwidth, because it's fixed for all bars. But other transitions seem tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of calling D3 transition in a React component with `useEffect`:

```js
const {useRef, useState, useEffect} = React;

const Chart = () => {
  const [rectWidth, setRectWidth] = useState(100);
  
  const svgRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const width = 50 + Math.random() * 200;
      setRectWidth(width);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (svgRef.current) {
      d3.select(svgRef.current)
        .select('rect')
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
    }
  }, [rectWidth, svgRef]);

  return (
      <svg ref={svgRef} width={300} height={100}>
        <rect x={10} y={10} height={20} />
      </svg>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.querySelector("#chart"))
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: white;
}

rect {
  stroke: none;
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I am aware of this imperative method where we use the native d3 api inside React. But I am trying to avoid it because React now supports `svg` elements in JSX, and thus I want to use the declarative method in JSX, which makes things much easier and human-readable, except when it comes to animation/transition, which I am trying to implement from scratch using `react-spring`.

Comment: If you use D3 scale functionality, there is no problem in using other D3 features like transition

Comment: Fair enough. So, how can I incorporate the transition functionality in my code, without changing it to imperative?

Comment: Just like in the snippet: get ref from the SVG element with `useRef`, catch the data change in `useEffect` and call transition for the appropriate D3 selection